# Could "Terry" be a diminutive for Peter or Walter?

Tags: names, nicknames, diminutives, hypocorisms

I know "Terry" is used as a given name, and derives from french Thierry. It could also be used as a nickname for e.g. Terence. Here the first syllable of the given name is used as the stem in the nickname. Another way to form such diminutive nicknames is to use the last syllable of the given name for the nickname, as in "Betty" for Elizabeth. Analogue to this, I wonder if Terry is sometimes used for Peter or Walter?

Comment: Any name can be used as a nickname, but "Terry" doesn't really flow from Peter or Walter—at least *I've* never heard it used that way. Pete or Walt are the usual ones.

Comment: You're confusing **nickname** (eg  'Satchmo', 'Dipper Mouth' or 'Pops' for _Louis Armstrong_) with **diminutive** (eg 'Ted' for 'Edward').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth i really don't think I've confused it. I have explicitly written "diminutive nicknames" in the Q

Comment: I will mildly point out that where I live (UK) 'Terry' is usually the diminutive of 'Terence', which does not, I believe, come from 'Thierry'.

Comment: Could I get a reason for the downvote, plase?

Comment: 'Terry' is obviously (from one answer) a sobriquet applied to at least one 'Walter'. But according to [this Wikipedia list](http://agreg-ink.net/index.php?title=English_First_Names_and_Their_Diminutive_Forms) it does not seem to be regarded as a diminutive form of either 'Walter' or 'Peter'. It would thus seem to be a nickname in isolated examples rather than a diminutive form. Diminutives formed from the last syllable/s of original names (eg Fred; Xander) are the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: I'm considering upvoting to offset the downvote; I think the way to go about researching this is not so obvious (and probably needs someone who's done post-grad work on diminutives/nicknames). But my Beth has arrived with Boy. Back later.

Comment: Does anyone really say:" Hi, I'm Gregory, but everybody calls me by my diminutive, Greg"    ?? I would think the word most would use is "nickname" and this is not due to any misunderstanding. Also, noone would claim you cannot say his name is John, he oght to be more specific, and use the term  "given name",. But then again, English is not my native language.

Comment: Ok, lots of downvotes, without explaination. How could I then improve the Question? :) Delete??

Comment: Can 'Terry' be used as a nickname for Peter or Walter? is like asking 'Can 'Groucho' be used as a nickname for Julius? Subject perhaps to laws of decency and or ability to pronounce names, 'Terry' can be used as a nickname for anybody, and  _anything_ can be used as a nickname for Peter, Walter, Julius or anyone else. // 'Is 'Terry' a diminutive form of 'Peter' and/or 'Walter'?' is a different matter. One could look first in the Wikipedia article mentioned.

Comment: My father was christened Royston because his father was chief engineer on a ship called the _Royston Grange_ at the time. He hated that name, and insisted on being called 'Bob'.

Comment: I proposed a change to the title because I think it's causing some confusion. I think the underlying question here is whether Terry has been used as a diminutive form of Peter or Walter. If the question is whether one can create such a thing, it's not really clear how to answer. Yes, you could, but it doesn't mean anyone else will follow. It'll really just be a nickname, which all sides seem to agree is not the question.

Comment: @jimm101 Your change of title made the question much better! Thanks for the constructive comment! :) I adjusted the title even further, in an effort to reduce the possibility of misinterpretations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terry as diminutive for Walter is not completely unknown. For instance, [in this 2017 book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KM6-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT212&lpg=PT212&dq=is%20%22terry%22%20nickname%20for%20%E2%80%9Cwalter%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=IKAAjPCbhP&sig=ACfU3U24tWvVmbx2z89hGFGmZVD_qbHm_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF1_v0pbXmAhX0uXEKHfYvDZEQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20%22terry%22%20nickname%20for%20%E2%80%9Cwalter%E2%80%9D&f=false), a character scolds another for saying “Terry” instead of “young Walter”.

Comment: Could this be a regional thing? The plot is in Ireland.

Comment: It is actually stated in the text that 'Terry' is here used as a _nickname_ (not a diminutive). It could have been 'Bob', 'Snowball', 'Stilge', 'Boojum', 'Trubshaw' ... (some I remember) – semantically unrelated to the original.

Comment: Good point, but it’s unlikely someone would use “diminutive” while terrorising their son.

Comment: Yes, but this example does not justify " 'Terry' as a diminutive for 'Walter' is not completely unknown" but rather " 'Terry' used as a nickname for someone with the name 'Walter' is not completely unknown".